# System.UnauthorizedAccessException error al guardar imagen

Tags: c#

estoy haciendo un programa para generar QR (soy nuevo), agregué una función para guardar la imagen del QR en la carpeta que seleccione el usuario, pero recibo una excepción System.UnauthorizedAccessException, ya intenté ejecutarlo como administrador y nada, espero me puedan ayudar y gracias, código:

```
public static void SaveInFolder(string ruta, string payload)
    {
        QRCodeGenerator qrGenerator = new QRCodeGenerator();
        QRCodeData qrData = qrGenerator.CreateQrCode(payload, QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel.H);
        QRCode qrCode = new QRCode(qrData);

        Bitmap img = qrCode.GetGraphic(8);
        img.SetResolution(1280.0f, 720.0f);
        Bitmap imgQR = new Bitmap(img, new Size(800, 800));

        byte[] imgToSave = ImageToByte(imgQR);

        File.WriteAllBytes(ruta, imgToSave); // <---- Linea de la excepción

        MessageBox.Show($"Archivo guardado correctamente en: \n{ruta}", "Guardado Exitosamente");
    }
```

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir más detalles del error que se genera?. Hay varias razones por las que se pueda generar esa excepción.

Comment: Mi programa funciona así: Se abre un FolderBrowser y se llama a este metodo, pero en la linea marcada, se genera la excepción, es como si no tuviera permisos de escritura, pero intenté ejecutarlo como adminsitrador y nada :(

Comment: Entiendo, pero lo que sucede es que ese error también puede presentarse por otras razones. Por ejemplo que estés especificando un directorio en la ruta.

Comment: No te entiendo, la ruta es pasada mediante el FolderBrowser.

Comment: Lo que estoy tratando de decir es que el método `File.WriteAllBytes` recibe como primer parámetro una ruta, pero esta debe ser una ruta de un archivo, no de un directorio. Y pues sin haber visto la ruta podría ser una de las causas por las que se genera el error.

Comment: Mmmmm, por ejemplo, le pasa la ruta C:/Users/Usuarios/Desktop, ¿Crees qué ese sea el problema?

Comment: Es una opción, puedes intentar escribir esto en la línea donde se arroja la excepción. `File.WriteAllBytes(ruta + "/qr.bmp", imgToSave)`.

Comment: Gracias man, me funcionó usando 
`File.WriteAllBytes(ruta + "/qr-generate.png", imgToSave);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La excepción `UnauthorizedAccessException` no solo se genera cuando no se cuenta con los privilegios suficientes para acceder a la ruta.

Otras razones por las que se puede generar el error al invocar `File.WriteAllBytes` son:

- La ruta especifica un archivo de solo lectura
- La ruta especifica un archivo que está escondido
- La operación no es soportada en la plataforma actual
- La ruta especifica un directorio, en vez de un archivo

En tu caso, la razón por la que se puede estar generando el error, es porque no estas especificando el archivo en la ruta.

Lo siguiente debería resolverlo.

```
File.WriteAllBytes(ruta + "/qr-generate.png", imgToSave);
```